# Evaluate the testset of an object detection model with IoU metric

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo

IoU is a value used in object detection to measure the overlap of a predicted versus actual bounding box for an object.

In my case I am trying to calculate the IoU between the ground truth and the detected Bbox in YOLOv5 object detection model.

to do so I:

1. extracted the bboxes of the ground truth and the detection ones.
2. covert those coordination into a binary image.
3. calculate the IoU of the hole class.

here I deal with all the BBoxes in a single shot, see code :

```
def extract_BBoxes(path_annot):
  """code to get al the bboxes"""

def draw_boxes(boxes, h, w):
  a = np.zeros((h,w), np.uint8)
  for box in boxes:
    cv2.rectangle(a,(box[0],box[1]),(box[2],box[3]),(255,0,0),-1)
  return a

def iou(im1, im2):
  if im1.shape != im2.shape:
    print('images are not similar: check the size')
    exit(-1)
  inter = 0
  union = 0
  for i in range(im1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(im1.shape[1]):
      if im1[i][j] and im2[i][j]:
        inter += 1
      if im1[i][j] or im2[i][j]:
        union += 1
  print('{} , {}, {}'.format(inter, union,inter/union))
  return inter, union, inter/union
```

I am asking if there is a way to do it by calculating the IoU of the BBox with its corresponding BBox in the ground truth, because that would be more accurate.(how to know the corresponding box of each box in the detected boxes).